# JSON Object Property Missing Quotation Marks?

Tags: node.js, json

I have a very trivial problem, and I'm having trouble finding similar questions. On my Node JS server, I prepare an object of key-value pairs. The keys that have spaces in them are converted to strings like this `{'key':'value'}`. However, the keys without spaces or special characters don't have quotes surrounding them. When I print it out it looks like this `{key:'value'}`. The problem is, when I send the response back to the client, the keys without surrounding quotes are missing from the object. So how would I surround all the keys with quotes then so that it is sent properly?

Comment: Use JSON.stringify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON Objects must follow the [RFC-7159](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159), the easiest way to get a RFC-compliant JSON object is to use `JSON.stringify` on the object you want to output on your server side, which is natively supported in NodeJS.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to convert the response to client by converting the javascript object to JSON object.

var object = { key: 'value' };

var newObject = JSON.stringify(object);
console.log("format : ", newObject);

//the JSON.stringify() function definition, it will simply turn the object log into a JSON string.

OUTPUT:
format : '{ 'key' : 'value' }'